# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 1."

Tags: ios, json, swift, objectmapper

This is the json string returned from a server. I am trying to Map it to a object mapper class and print values but I get the following error.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 1."

```
{'Status': False, 'updatedStatus': True, 'connectionStatus': True}
```

And following is my mapper class

```
public class Info: Mappable {


    internal let kStatusKey: String = "Status"
    internal let kConnectionStatusKey: String = "connectionStatus"
    internal let kupdatedStatusKey: String = "updatedStatus"


    // MARK: Properties
    public var Status: String?
    public var connectionStatus: String?
    public var updatedStatus: String?



    // MARK: ObjectMapper Initalizers
    /**
     Map a JSON object to this class using ObjectMapper
     - parameter map: A mapping from ObjectMapper
     */
    required public init?(_ map: Map){

    }

    /**
     Map a JSON object to this class using ObjectMapper
     - parameter map: A mapping from ObjectMapper
     */
    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        Status <- map[kStatusKey]
        connectionStatus <- map[kConnectionStatusKey]
        updatedStatus <- map[kUpdatedStatusKey]

    }
}
```

I cannot change the string returned from the server, Is there any way I can fix my code.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 1."` response is from server? or it appears when `mapping` method is called?

Comment: That is *not* valid JSON (try it at http://jsonlint.com). Strings must be enclosed in `"..."`, not `'...'`, see http://www.json.org.

Comment: @MartinR is right. This : `{
 "Status": "False",
 "updatedStatus": "True",
 "connectionStatus": "True"
}` is valid json.

Comment: ... and booleans are `true`, `false` in *lowercase*. Fix your server.

Comment: It appears when mapping is called

Answer (score 10):

Your JSON should look like this:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "updatedStatus": true,
    "connectionStatus": true
}
```

Update your mapper upon this.